# string::find is not finding match

Tags: c++, string

Im trying to use the string::find method to determine if the string " hello " (with space before and after) exists in a line of a .txt file. if it does, its supposed to print out the line number(position isnt important). the problem is, its not finding the string. please help.

```
int main() {
    string key (" hello ");
    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("test.txt");
    string s;
    int lineCount = 1;
    int found;
    if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
        while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
            getline(myReadFile, s);
            found = s.find(key);
            if(found != string::npos) {
                cout<<lineCount<<endl;
                lineCount++;
            }
         }
    }
    myReadFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run it in the debugger and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Note: `string::find()` does **not** return an `int`. Please use std::string::size_type.

Comment: Martin: while I do prefer that structure also, the OP's program doesn't actually mishandle the last line; `getline` will clear the string if you try to read a line after the last one.  So there is always an extra run through the loop with `s` being empty, but this won't make the output wrong.

Comment: @Martin: correct, but the stream won't be in the bad state until after the read is attempted (this is the condition of the while loop).  In other words, after reading the last line, the stream is still good (because no reads have failed).  So the loop runs once more, and getline clears the string, then sees EOF.  This is different from using `>>` (which is what commonly causes errors) because it skips whitespace before clearing the string, and the stream can go bad during that part.

Comment: @Sumudu: Yep. Deleting comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it seems to be doing as you have it is just counting the number of lines that have that string in them.  You should increment the line number var in every iteration of the loop, not just when the string is found.

```
int main() {
    std::string key (" hello ");
    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("test.txt");


    if (myReadFile) {

        std::string line;
        int line_number = 0;
        while (std::getline(myReadFile, line)) {
            line_number++;                
            if (line.find(key) != std::string::npos)
                std::cout << line_number << std::endl;
        }

    } else {
        std::cout << "Error opening file\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't see any use of the `if (myReadFile)`

Answer (score 2):

If the problem you're seeing is that your program always prints 1, 2, 3, ... instead of the correct line numbers, it's because you only increment `lineCount` if the substring was found; to fix it move `lineCount++` to after the `if(found != string::npos)` block.

If you're not seeing any output at all, either the file doesn't contain `" hello "` (case matters, and also those space characters won't match other whitespace) or "test.txt" isn't in the right place or has the wrong name.

NOTE: The comparison between `found` and `string::npos` is OK here (even though one is a signed `int` and the other is a `size_t` (probably `unsigned int` or possibly `unsigned long long` on a 64-bit system).  Interestingly, it will break if you change `found` to an `unsigned int` and `size_t` happens to be a wider unsigned type (on a 32-bit machine, you can simulate this situation by making `found` an `unsigned short`).  Since you don't actually use the value of `found`, it's probably best to avoid conversions altogether and just do `if (s.find(key) != string::npos)`.

Answer (score 0):

`int found` should be `string::size_type`.  This may be your issue since int is signed and size_t is unsigned.  See [string::npos](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/) for more info.

> npos is a static member constant value
>   with the greatest possible value for
>   an element of type size_t.

EDIT:

Thanks to Martin's comments I replaced `size_t` with `string::size_type`

Comment: ah thanks, i had it that way earlier then i must have fixed another issue and forgot to change it.

Comment: According to my copy of the standard npos (and find) have the type std::string::size_type

Comment: @Martin: That's strange I've always used it as size_t

Comment: Most implementations use size_t as the type for std::string::size_type (ie inside string there is `typedef std::size_t size_type`) but technically they are different.

Comment: @Martin: Ah okay I get what you are saying now, that's good to know thank you